# Drag Move an Image inside a Circle (circular movement)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I drawn a circle in canvas and put an image near the border. Now I have absolutely no idea..I want to drag the image around the circle but the top of the arrow image should always be on the border.
For Example: I drag the arrow from the top to the left at nine o'clock. Now the arrow image needs to be rotated 90 degrees.

http://jsfiddle.net/L5twk3ak/1/

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('test');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var points = [];
var radius = 55;

imageBG = new Image();
imageBG.onload = function() {context.drawImage(imageBG, 148, 100, 15, 15);};
imageBG.src = 'https://www.nanamee.com/upload/images/5945/5945_p.jpg';

for(var degree = 0; degree < 360; degree++)
{
 var radians = degree * Math.PI / 179;
 var x = 150 + radius * Math.cos(radians);
 var y = 150 + radius * Math.sin(radians);
 points.push({x : x, y : y});
}

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(points[0].x + 4, points[0].y + 4)

for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++)
{
 var pt = points[i];
   
 context.lineTo(pt.x + 4, pt.y + 4);
}

context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.stroke(); 
context.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="400" height="400">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: What I don't understand is: why you did not do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/L5twk3ak/2/ (using a simple **arc**); where is your code where you listen for the mouse position inside the canvas? Where are your drag events? Where's the math?

Answer (score 1):

You need to :

- Draw your Arc as we're supposed to (unless you have better plans with `lineTo()` )
- calculate the mouse position inside the canvas - on mousemove.
- calculate the resultant degree depending on Mouse Position vs. the Arc center.
- cache your image for reuse
- create draw functions (one for the Arc, the other for drawing the Image after translating the canvas context). That way on (click+drag) mousemove you can simply reuse them to draw your objects into Canvas.

<sub>I'll not show you how to implement the click+drag cause it's ***pretty trivial***: you simply need to apply your draw functions if both CLICK+MOUSEMOVE are registered.</sub>

Here's the interesting calculations part:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('test'); // Store in variable!
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var circle = {rad: 55, x:100, y:100};         // Object for ease of use
var img = {src:'//placehold.it/13x13/000', x:0 ,y:0, w:13, h:13};
var arrowImg; // Store for later Image reference

function drawArc(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.rad, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke(); 
    context.closePath();
}
function drawImg( deg ){
    context.save(); // save before we mess with ctx translations
    context.translate(circle.y, circle.x); // temporarily translate the ctx 
                                           // to the Arc center coordinates.
    context.rotate(deg*Math.PI/180); // we need Radians so deg*Math.PI/180
    context.drawImage(arrowImg, circle.rad-img.w, -img.h/2);
    context.restore(); // restore to default
}
function calcDeg(e){ // Retrieve degree from mouse position vs. arc center
    var mPos = {
      x : e.pageX-canvas.offsetLeft-circle.x,
      y : e.pageY-canvas.offsetTop-circle.y
    }; 
    var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.y, mPos.x);    
    return getAtan*180/Math.PI;
}

drawArc();                                    // Draw the ARc
arrowImg = new Image();                       // Create Image Obj
arrowImg.onload = function(){ drawImg(-90) }; // onload draw the Image
arrowImg.src = img.src;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt){
    canvas.width = canvas.width; // clear the canvas
    drawArc();                   // Draw Arc
    drawImg( calcDeg(evt) );     // Draw Image at the calculated degree
}, false);
```

```css
canvas{background:#eee;}
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="400" height="400">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

<sub>Not clear? Goog, than ask</sub>